# Can a method return 2 booleans?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 boolean values which I want to return from the same method.
This doesn't seem to work. They are always set to false no matter what.

Have I made a mistake in my approach or is there other way(s) to do this?

```
    bool isRetry = false;
    bool isContinue = false;

    BeginRetrieveVehicleInfo(isRetry, isContinue);

    if (!isContinue)
    {
        _beginInspectionButton.Enabled = true;
        return;
    }

    if (!isRetry)
    {
        BeginInspection();
    }
```

**BeginRetrieveVehicleInfo** method code:

```
    PleaseWaitForm pleaseWaitDialog = new PleaseWaitForm("Registration plate read in progress...", "Please Wait");

    pleaseWaitDialog.Show();
    AlprListener AlprListener = new AlprListener();
    string plateString = AlprListener.RunServer();
    pleaseWaitDialog.Close();

    if (plateString == "No response received!" || plateString == "")
    {
        ApplusMessageBox.Show("No response received from Camera!", "Warning");
        return isRetry = false;
    }
    else if (plateString != _vehicle.RegistrationID)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = ApplusMessageBox.Show("Camera detected an invalid Registration Plate. Do you want to continue?", "Warning: Camera detected an invalid Registration Plate!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            return isContinue = true;
        }
        else
        {
            return isContinue = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return isRetry = false;
    }
```

Comment: You can return an instance of a class that has two bool-properties or make them `ref` or `out` parameters.

Comment: Or use value-tuples in C#7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameters are passed *by value* by default (even references are passed by value, which is confusing util you grok it).

If you want the changes to be visible to the caller, you must pass them *by reference* - so add `ref` before both parameter names, and add `ref` to the call-site:

```
BeginRetrieveVehicleInfo(ref isRetry, ref isContinue);
```

and

```
void BeginRetrieveVehicleInfo(ref bool x, ref bool y) {...}
```

It could also be `out` if it doesn't need to use the input values.

Alternatively, consider returning a tuple:

```
(bool X, bool Y) BeginRetrieveVehicleInfo() {
    ...
    return (oneBool, anotherBool);
}
```

with

```
var result = BeginRetrieveVehicleInfo();
if(result.X) {...}
```

Comment: Pass by reference is what he was searching for. He just didn't frame the question properly.

Comment: @Prajwal I disagree - although I would concede that that is *how they were trying to do it*; pass by reference is just one of many ways to achieve multiple return values - and now that we have value tuples, it probably wouldn't be my first choice in most cases.

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦ Thank you very much for this clear answer.

Comment: Doesn't c# 7 also support tuple deconstruction?  `bool (bool1, bool2) = BeginRetrieveVehicleInfo();   if (bool1) { ... }`  I'm not 100% sure of the syntax.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway yes it does; lots of options